# Change a sprite image overtime

Tags: python, image, pygame, sprite

Hi i have an object wich is a spacecraft and i want it to change the color (change the image) when i press a button  here is my object:

```
class soucoupe(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


def __init__(self, image, height, speed):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

    self.speed = -2
    self.image = pygame.Surface([64, 34])
    self.image = blus # this is the image

    self.pos = image.get_rect()
    self.pos.x=520
    self.pos.y=680
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

def move(self):
    global dpush
    global gpush

    if dpush and gpush ==1 or dpush and gpush ==0:  
        self.pos = self.pos.move(0*self.speed, 0)
    if dpush==1:
        self.pos = self.pos.move(-self.speed, 0)
    if gpush==1:
        self.pos = self.pos.move(self.speed, 0)
```

i tried when button is press: 
soucoupe.image= image2 
but it doesn't work the image is still the same, it looks simple to solve but i have no clue.

Comment: You havent posted all the code. You should also check out the established guidelines for writing code see PEP-8

Answer (score 0):

You didn't all of the relevant code, but you said you do:

```
soucoupe.image= image2
```

with would set the `image` attribute of the `soucoupe` *class*.

That's not the same as setting an attribute of the *instance* of a class.

Somewhere you probably create an instance of `soucoupe`, like

```
something = soucoupe(image, height, speed)
```

Then you have to set the `image` attribute of `something`

```
something.image = image2
```

---

There are some other issues with your code, but these are out of scope of this answer.

Comment: Ok thx I understand now i solved this problem, i'm sorry i'm starting you said about other issues in the code. could you point them to me if you have the time of course

Comment: Examples: why do you set `self.image` two times? Why do you store the  position in `self.pos` and `self.rect`?

Comment: Yeah that was some tests that i made i should have delete that you are right.